# Can appium be detected as bot?

Tags: appium, appium-ios, appium-android

Hi i just discovered appium and it looks promising to use on my next project
Basically i want to use real android phones and emulate chrome to visit and perform actions on specific websites like login etc
My question is can appium be detected as a bot? Does it share variables that can be detected just like in selenium?
If yes what do i need to change modify to the web driver?
And what about emulator case?

I tested the website and logged in fine but im worry more about long-term.

I'm fairly new to this and did not see a same question online
Thanks

Comment: Anybody can answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Appium is **black-box automation tool**, so all the interactions are done **without your app/ device modification**.
I don't see a case when its session can be detected as bot. However it cannot handle Captcha, FaceID, FingerPrint, etc. so you should be precise on what scenarios you want to automate.

Comment: what about using an emulator, can the sites detect screen pixels like they are not real phone? Also what about guid, how do i set a unique guid on emulator and real phone? Always talking about chrome

Comment: While app can't really detect Appium, it can certainly detect an emulator enviroment.